# Eclipse: Thrift inside Tomcat Servlet, ClassNotFoundException TException

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, thrift

I'm trying to make a Java servlet that can make Apache Thrift calls, but I'm having trouble starting the servlet.

I have a **thrift client**, a Java class for making calls to the thrift server

```
public class ThriftClient {

    static TTransport transport;
    static TProtocol protocol;
    static MyService.Client client;

    static long xtk_pointer;

    public static void openSocket() throws TException {
        transport = new TSocket("localhost", 9090);
        transport.open();

        protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
        client = new MyService.Client(protocol);
    }
```

and I have a **java servlet** which opens a socket through the thrift client

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        out.println("Hello World");
    }

    void startThrift(String [] args) {
        try {
            ThriftClient.openSocket();
```

However, when I try to run this servlet (using eclipse and a tomcat server), I get an error like

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
```

and a `ClassNotFoundException` for `org.apache.thrift.TException`

**EDIT: All I had to do was include the thrift jars into the Tomcat Server's classpath. See my answer below**

I have used the thrift client already without any ClassNotFoundExceptions, and the servlet works on its own as well. However, once I add `ThriftClient.openSocket();` into the servlet, it breaks, so I have a feeling Thrift and Tomcat are clashing somehow. Any ideas?

Edit: The weird part is that I never call the method `startThrift()` but I still get the error.

Comment: Did you try to catch the exception? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I'm using eclipse to run the servlet, so I'm not entirely sure how to catch the exception or print the stack trace

Comment: You can call `exception.printStackTrace()` inside the catch block and you should see the stack trace in the Eclipse console.

Comment: It seems the main issues is a ClassNotFoundException for the thrift class `TException`, but I never ran into this issue before...

Answer (score 0):

While you included the thrift jars into your project, you also have to add them to the Tomcat library as well

First make sure your external jars are in your project Java Build Path...

1. right click your project, click `Properties`
2. Under `Deployment Assembly`, click `Add...`
3. Double click `Java Build Path Entries...` and select the jars/libraries you want to include